# Add include header generated in configure_file

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake project with an application and a library. The library has one header file generated with `configure_file`. The problem is that the application code cannot find the generated header file.

What is the proper way to include the generated header file path to the application `-I` options? `target_link_libraries` adds the path, but to the *source* but not to the *binary* directory?
Is it possible to add a property to the library when `add_library` is used so that this property can be used when `target_link_libraries` is used?

Comment: Include directories are added with `target_include_directories` command. You may pass **absolute path** to this command and CMake will preserve this path. Not sure what is a problem. Could you prepare [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have generated your header file with

```
configure_file(config.h.in config.h @ONLY)
```

and have your library target already created with

```
add_library(libtarget ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

it's simply a call to

```
target_include_directories(libtarget PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

under the assumption that all commands are given in this order and are located in the same `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: This will help with building the said library. But I need this `config.h` to be used by some other application.

Comment: I was under the impression that the library and the application belong to the same CMake project. And that should work, as the library target will propagate PUBLIC and INTERFACE properties (include directories, compile options and definitions) to the application that links against it.

Comment: @ilya1725 If you do a `make install` step, the configured header will be installed into the target install directory.